# Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate] is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm upgrading Laravel from 5.2 to 5.3

I followed the steps mentioned here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

When I tried to to do composer update I kept getting:

```
[2021-04-12 06:15:52] build.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException' with message 'Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate] is not instantiable.' in XXXXXXXXXXXX/admin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:763
#0 /Users/ahmad/Projects/admin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(644): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Illuminate\\Cont...', Array)
#1 /Users/ahmad/Projects/admin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\\Cont...', Array)
#2 /Users/ahmad/Projects/admin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1203): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#3 /Users/ahmad/Projects/admin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(175): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#4 /Users/ahmad/Projects/admin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(144): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::resolveFacadeInstance('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#5 /Users/ahmad/Projects/admin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(231): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::getFacadeRoot()
#6 /Users/ahmad/Projects/admin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php(25): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('policy', Array)
#7 /Users/ahmad/Projects/admin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php(25): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::policy('XXXXXX\\Model', 'XXXXXXX\\Polic...')
#8 /Users/ahmad/Projects/admin/app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider->registerPolicies()
#9 [internal function]: XXXXXX\Providers\AuthServiceProvider->boot()
```

I added the Gate to my providers array, and tried clearing the bootstrap cache folder and delete the vendor, and reinstall everything in the composer.json

Any advises?

Comment: put your code please

Comment: You can try to clean all with this command `composer clearcache` and after `rm -rf vendor/*` and then reinstall `composer install` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade from an older version of Laravel, it may contain some old files or code which are not needed. In my case, I needed to update `config/app.php` file as per the latest code and it fixed the error.